# Dynamic group name display for list view in BB 10 cascades and also in Android

Tags: android, blackberry-10, cascade, blackberry-cascades

I am working on **BB 10 cascades** application and **Android** application.
I have a requirement i.e, I should display a list view which is sorted according to their groups but in UI the group name should display only the 1st list item which is appearing on top of the screen. when I scroll the list view the group name should also change accordingly.

For example I have a list view with group

Cricket {Bat, Ball}, Dress {Shirt, Pant}, Computer{Keyboard, mouse}

Check the following image to understand[image]

When I scroll the list the heading should change according to the 1st item appear on the screen
[image]

Please help...

Comment: You should make two separate questions for Android and BlackBerry 10, as the answers will be completely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For BlackBerry 10, you will need to use a [GroupDataModel](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/ui/lists/groupdatamodel.html), you will be able to set sortingKeys.

I am not familiar with Android development, but I think [this](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-expandable-list-view-example/) is what you are looking for. Since the values are stored in ArrayList, you will be able to do a `java.util.Collections.sort` before you add to the listview.